# Probability Generating Functions- Dependent Poisson Distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, generating-functions

I was wondering if anyone could give me a tip on how to proceed with the following question?

Suppose X~Poisson(N), where N~Poisson($\lambda$). What is the PGF of X + N? (Where $\lambda$  is a number)

I know that because the two distributions are not independent, you can't use the normal rules of PGF and multiply the two together. Thanks!

Comment: compound distribution function?

Comment: thanks @Chinny84 I'll have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the definition in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function) , the probability generating function of a random variable $Y$ is given by
$$G(z)=\mathbb{E}[z^{Y}].$$

First, if $Y\sim Poisson(\mu)$ then $\mathbb{E}[z^{Y}]=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}z^{k}\frac{e^{-\mu}\mu^{k}}{k!}=e^{\mu(z-1)}$. Using this result repeatedly and [conditional expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation) we can write

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{E}[z^{X+N}]&=&\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[z^{X+N}|N]]\\
&=&\mathbb{E}[z^{N}e^{N(z-1)}]\\
&=& \mathbb{E}[e^{N(z+\log z-1)}]\\
&=&\exp[\lambda(e^{z+\log z-1}-1)]=\exp[\lambda(ze^{z-1}-1)].
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thank you @Indrajit that's what I thought but it sort of looks a little ugly with the two exponentials so I was questioning myself!